# Output freezing when using a python script to run a bash script which runs another script

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, popen

I have always been able to use Python's subprocess.Popen to run bash scripts without any issues.

However, I am now trying to run a bash script with Popen, and then that bash script is trying to run another script. I did not redirect the output that Popen was getting at all, so all of the output would appear on the terminal. I'm using Ubuntu Linux.

However, when the script that is being called by the bash script finishes, the output on the terminal freezes while the rest of the bash script and the python script continues in the background.
I understand that it might not be the smoothest practice to have a python script run a bash script which also runs a bash script, but I'm hoping to fix this issue. I sense that it is an issue with how I'm running the original bash script inside my python script. Here is the code I'm using:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "myScript.sh", param1, param2, param3])
p.wait()
```

I originally was using `shell=True` for the Popen, but that was resulting in the same issue. I also tried removing `p.wait()` but that also does not resolve the issue.

Any ideas? Should I use a different python method to run the bash script?

Comment: Did you try `p.communicate()` ?

Comment: Yes, that still did not work (same issue).

Comment: does it work with a simple bash script? Can you workaround by sourcing the internal bash script instead of calling another bash?

Comment: Are you interested in parsing the output? If not, try `subprocess.call()`. `subprocess.popen()`, as the name suggests, uses pipes and this could quickly deadlock as pipe buffers fill up.